# Flexbox with fixed element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If I have a flexbox container with a fixed child, but it does not seem to wrap elements correctly:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child-1"></div>
  <div id="child-2"></div>
</div>

#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#child-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  position: fixed;
}
#child-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Comment: `#child-1` is out of the document flow and so will be ignored by the parent flex-container. It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

Add **position:sticky;** and **top:0;** to the #child-1 instead of position fixed;

Answer (score -1):

I have fixed this with:

- parent:

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
- child 1:

  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
- child 2

  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;